# Upvoting ♥: Lower comment upvote timeout

Tags: support, feature-request

stuff,

I honestly read fast. And I understand English quite well. Please lower the 5sec. timeout. I know when I want to upvote a comment. Please lower it at least for "trusted" users. If you already state that you *trust* us, then please really do it everywhere.

Comment: It is a minor annoyance, but it _is_ an annoyance. I am with you on this one.